# Avoid React-Native manual changes for iOS production build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm following the React-Native documentation for building iOS for production, located here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production

I find these instructions very strange, because it tells you to manually edit files and xcode settings. It seems extremely annoying and error-prone having to do this every time you want to create a new release.

Is there a reasonable way to automate this or use some kind of conditional for dev/prod?